# Is there a way in unix to programmatically force a terminal window to "front"

Tags: unix, solaris

We have a script that always runs in a terminal window.  Sometimes users will do stuff in other windows and our script terminal gets moved behind all these other windows, and they forget to bring it back to the front.  Is there a way to force it so it is always on top or front?  Sort of like how annoying popup windows work?  We are on solaris 8

Comment: Window stacking order is controlled by the window manager. Which one do you use?

Comment: @Joni I haven't a clue, how could I find out?

Comment: @jony Under Solaris 8, the window manager is more than likely CDE's `dtwm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way indeed! Check out a tool called xdotool.  It does exactly what you need and more.

Here is the link to the download: http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/#idp20144
and here is the link to the documentation: http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml

I suggest you look into the Window commands, especially: windowactivate
I can give you the exact command if you like to save time? Or you can browse through the documentation. Hope this helps!